# Convert node package to React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, node-modules

I am struggling to integrate CinetPay in React Native app. They are giving solution in Node package or CDN javascript. I have installed node package from https://www.npmjs.com/package/cinetpay-nodejs.
Now I need to convert this node package to work with React native app.

Code for node_modules/cinetpay-nodejs/index.js

```
var cdn = document.createElement('script');  
cdn.setAttribute('src','https://cinetpay.com/cdn/seamless_sdk/latest/cinetpay.prod.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(cdn);
module.exports = require('./lib/cinetpay');
```

How can I convert this code into React Native code?

Comment: It may already work.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: It is showing error
`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: document`

Answer (score 0):

If you like to ok integrate cinetpay in React native app you need to use axios and do request like this:

```
    var axios = require('axios');
    var data = JSON.stringify({
      "apikey": "YOUR_APIKEY",
      "site_id": "YOUR_SITEID",
      "transaction_id":  Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000).toString(), //
      "amount": 100,
      "currency": "XOF",
      "alternative_currency": "",
      "description": " TEST INTEGRATION ",
      "customer_id": "172",
      "customer_name": "KOUADIO",
      "customer_surname": "Francisse",
      "customer_email": "harrissylver@gmail.com",
      "customer_phone_number": "+225004315545",
      "customer_address": "Antananarivo",
      "customer_city": "Antananarivo",
      "customer_country": "CM",
      "customer_state": "CM",
      "customer_zip_code": "065100",
      "notify_url": "https://webhook.site/d1dbbb89-52c7-49af-a689-b3c412df820d",
      "return_url": "https://webhook.site/d1dbbb89-52c7-49af-a689-b3c412df820d",
      "channels": "ALL",
      "metadata": "user1",
      "lang": "FR",
      "invoice_data": {
        "Donnee1": "",
        "Donnee2": "",
        "Donnee3": ""
      }
    });

    var config = {
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://api-checkout.cinetpay.com/v2/payment',
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data : data
    };

    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

You can have more indicated in the documentation in [this link](https://docs.cinetpay.com/api/1.0-fr/checkout/initialisation)